# QiskitBackendNotFoundError - Unable to run the backend using BackendEstimator primitive

Tags: qiskit, programming, ibm-quantum-devices

I am trying to run a small quantum circuit and generate the expectation value of an observable using the `BackendEstimator` primitive by incorporating the noise model from `Fake20QV1` backend. Below is a snippet of the code.

```
qc = QuantumCircuit(3,3)
qc.x(0)
qc.x(1)
qc.h(2)
qc.x(2)

qc.measure(range(3), range(3))
observable = SparsePauliOp("ZZZ")
#qc.draw('mpl')
```

```
# Get the noise model of Fake20VQ1
backend_fake = Fake20QV1()
noise_model = noise.NoiseModel.from_backend(backend_fake)

# Get coupling map from backend
coupling_map = backend_fake.configuration().coupling_map

# Get basis gates from noise model
basis_gates = noise_model.basis_gates

# Perform a noisy simulation
backend = AerSimulator(noise_model=noise_model,
                       coupling_map=coupling_map,
                       basis_gates=basis_gates, shots=1024)
transpiled_circuit = transpile(qc, backend)
result = backend.run(transpiled_circuit).result()
```

Now, there are two ways in which I tried to run the circuit :

Alternative #1

```
counts = result.get_counts(0)
expectation_value = sampled_expectation_value(counts, observable)
plot_histogram(counts)
expectation_value
```

Runs successfully and gives the expected outputs.

Alternative #2 (using BackendSampler and BackendEstimator)

```
with Session(backend=backend_fake):
    sampler = BackendSampler()
    estimator = BackendEstimator()
    result1 = sampler.run(qc).result()
    print(f"Quasi-probability distribution: {result1.quasi_dists[0]}")

    result2 = estimator.run(qc, observable).result()
    print(f"EV : {result2.values[0]}")
```

Generates **QiskitBackendNotFoundError: 'No backend matches the criteria.'**

```
File ~/anaconda3/envs/qem/lib/python3.12/site-packages/qiskit_ibm_runtime/qiskit_runtime_service.py:779, in QiskitRuntimeService.backend(self, name, instance)
    763 """Return a single backend matching the specified filtering.
    764 
    765 Args:
   (...)
    776     QiskitBackendNotFoundError: if no backend could be found.
    777 """
    778 # pylint: disable=arguments-differ, line-too-long
--> 779 backends = self.backends(name, instance=instance)
    780 if not backends:
    781     cloud_msg_url = ""
...
--> 539         raise QiskitBackendNotFoundError("No backend matches the criteria.")
    540     if not self._backends[name] or instance_filter != self._backends[name]._instance:
    541         self._set_backend_config(name)

QiskitBackendNotFoundError: 'No backend matches the criteria.'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Qiskit has been updated, many things have been moved here and there, also the noise model fake backends that you are using. This is how you should run it in accordance with the recently updated Qiskit package.

## Necessary Imports

```python
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
from qiskit.quantum_info import SparsePauliOp
from qiskit_aer import AerSimulator
from qiskit_ibm_runtime.fake_provider import FakeVigo  # fake noisy backends are moved to ibm_runtime, do pip install qiskit-ibm-runtime before
from qiskit import transpile
from qiskit.result import sampled_expectation_value
from qiskit.visualization import plot_histogram
from qiskit.primitives import BackendEstimator, BackendSampler
```

## Making the Quantum Circuit

```python
qc = QuantumCircuit(3,3)
qc.x(0)
qc.x(1)
qc.h(2)
qc.x(2)

qc.measure(range(3), range(3))
observable = SparsePauliOp("ZZZ")
qc.draw('mpl',style="iqp")
```

## Selecting the Noisy Backend and transpiling

```python
device_backend = FakeVigo()
sim_vigo = AerSimulator.from_backend(device_backend)
transpiled_circuit = transpile(qc, sim_vigo)  # this step is necessary
```

## Running a Noisy Simulation

```python
result = sim_vigo.run(transpiled_circuit).result()
counts = result.get_counts(0)
expectation_value = sampled_expectation_value(counts, observable)

expectation_value
```

or getting the plot:

```python
plot_histogram(counts)
```

## Alternative Method

```python
sampler = BackendSampler(backend=sim_vigo)
estimator = BackendEstimator(backend=sim_vigo)
result1 = sampler.run(qc).result()
print(f"Quasi-probability distribution: {result1.quasi_dists[0]}")

result2 = estimator.run(qc, observable).result()
print(f"EV : {result2.values[0]}")
```

You have to specify the backend in the argument of `BackendSampler` and `BackendEstimator`. This code will run.

Comment: I used the backend class Fake20QV1 from qiskit.provider.fake_provider module defined in qiskit 1.0.2 (from qiskit documentation). Does it mean that many modules/classes in the updated version are deprecated/unsupported?

Comment: I think i missed the "Legacy Interface" part mentioned with V1 Fake backends in the qiskit.providers.fake_provider module's documentation. So it does seems unsupported now.

Comment: They are not yet, maybe soon they will, but I can't import them from the provider class. It suggests me to use fake_backends from the qiskit_ibm_provider class.  Yes, there are many changes from the previous qiskit 0.46.0 to the present qiskit 1.0.0

Comment: FYI Qiskit Runtime 0.22, just released, added a local testing mode for using fake backends, see https://docs.quantum.ibm.com/api/qiskit-ibm-runtime/runtime_service#local-testing-mode